# Remove the numeric portion of alphanumeric strings but keep the pure numbers

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm trying to clean some strings which contain a combination of letters and numbers

```
a <- c("Hello World","Hello4 World","12345","Hello World 4","4Hello World5","Hello 4", "Hello4")
```

I'm trying to remove the numeric portion of the alphanumeric strings but retain the pure numbers or when the number is separated by space, the output I'm looking for is.

```
b <- c("Hello World","Hello World","12345","Hello World 4","Hello World", "Hello 4","Hello")
```

The strings could be anything and not necessarily 'Hello' or 'World', I've tried various regex combinations but couldn't get what i wanted.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gsub('(?i)(?<=[a-z])\\d+|\\d+(?=[a-z])','',a,perl=T)
[1] "Hello World"   "Hello World"   "12345"         "Hello World 4" "Hello World"   "Hello 4"       "Hello"
```

## Explanation:

- `?i` is used to IGNORE CASES. ie you can also use the argument `ignore.case = TRUE`
- `(?<=[a-z])\\d+` This is a lookbehind whereby you are looking for digit(s) ie `\\d+ immediately preceded by a letter`(?<=[a-z])`
- `|` or
- `\\d+(?=[a-z])` this is a lookahead whereby you look for a digit(s) `\\d+` immediately followed by a letter `(?=[a-z])`.

Substitute this with an empty string. ie `replacement =''` is the second argument of the `gsub` function

```
gsub('([a-z])\\d+|\\d+([a-z])','\\1\\2',a,ignore.case = T)
[1] "Hello World"   "Hello World"   "12345"         "Hello World 4" "Hello World"   "Hello 4"       "Hello"
```

This follows almost the same trick but instead  of using lookarounds, we use backreferencing.

- `([a-z])\\d+`capture the letter that is immediately before a digit(s) as group 1
- `|\\d+([a-z])` capture the letter that immediately follows the digits
  as group 2

Now replace the whole expression with the captured letters ie `\\1\\2`

You can mix the two regular expressions as you want.

Comment: Could you explain the syntax as well?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of regex after splitting the input by space

```
[A-Za-z] - all letters 

^[0-9] - all digits
```

Comment: Can you please show how this code/instructions solve OP problem.